# C: evaluate 2 expressions in order and then return the first

Tags: c

Is there a more concise way to rewrite the following function without sacrificing clarity?

```
function uint64_t pop_int(uint8_t** p, int num_bytes)
{
   uint64_t res = decode_int(*p, num_bytes);
   *p += num_bytes;
   return res;
}
```

All I can think of is something like

```
return decode_int((*p += num_bytes) - num_bytes, num_bytes);
```

but it would be clearer if the language had something like a `FIRST` function that you could use like this:

```
return FIRST(decode_int(*p, num_bytes), *p += num_bytes);
```

but it would have to be clear that the arguments are evaluated in order.

Comment: Why? It's much more clear written the first way. Just trying to jam it all into one line (which surely is possible a number of ways) reduces the clarity IMHO. The two statements aren't related enough to warrant combining them.

Comment: Well, I think everything that shortens the code above WILL sacrifice clarity

Comment: This is very much opinion based. It's a review or golf problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and is opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, what you wrote is the idiomatic code for solving the task.

In languages with try-finally you could use that, and it may or may not be clearer. But C doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Not that it is useful for this answer, but check this out: https://gist.github.com/rampion/91594

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it... the syntax I needed was `({... ; expr})` (which is used in the CIRC_SPACE_TO_END macro in the linux kernel).
For my example, what I needed was:

```
#define POST_INC(type, a, b) ({type* tmp = a; a += b; tmp;})
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
  char const* str = "hello, world";
  printf("%s\n", POST_INC(char const, str, 5));
  printf("%s\n", POST_INC(char const, str, 2));
  printf("%s\n", POST_INC(char const, str, 5));
}
```

Result:

```
hello, world
, world
world
```

I'm glad I didn't give up!

Comment: if you wanted a macro solution, I am surprised that you didn't just write it yourself instead of searching for it...

Comment: I think this may be a good answer to some question, but not the original one. Yes, it can be used to implement the function `pop_int()` but not without sacrificing clarity. If you want to avoid the overhead of the function call, inlining the function would be clearer.

Comment: @nielsen Good point about clarity. I got a little too excited about the `({... ; expr})` syntax... maybe it's only useful in macros.